ENBW for non-white noise condition
The usual defininition of equivalent noise bandwidth (ENBW) seems to include a white-noise condition.  However, say I know the noise spectra of my signal is distributed differently, say pink noise. Should I be choosing a window based upon ENBW under a pink-noise condition?  If so, that implies there should be some window function that has maximal minimal ENBW for said condition (like the rectangular window for white-noise). Are such a windows known for pink-noise?
For context, I'm working with natural signals under biological processing whose frequency spectra are not white.

Accurate observation regarding the assumption of white noise for the ENBW solution. The choice of the window isn't the ENBW, the ENBW is a result for a given window. A primary reason for choosing a window is to increase the dynamic range of observing strong signals in the presence of weaker signals (at other frequencies) that may otherwise be buried in the very high sidelobes of the rectangular window's frequency response. We get that benefit at the expense of losing resolution bandwidth (ENBW).  To be clear, the rectangular window has the minimum ENBW compared to any other window that is highest in the center and tapers to the edges for purpose of sidelobe rejection. So the window isn't selected to maximize ENBW, but to minimize sidelobes and the increase in ENBW (which is not desired as we lose spectral resolution for a given capture duration) is a good trade to make given the impressive increase in dynamic range that can be achieved.
If there are no other strong signals and the content is pink noise alone, then I would recommend not doing any windowing (just the rectangular window) for this reason:  Pink noise has a $1/f$ power rolloff in the frequency domain. The sidelobes of the rectangular window go down at $1/f^2$ in power and thus the sidelobes due to the higher spectral content at the low frequencies will always be lower than the level of the higher frequencies. And thus for every actual frequency component, the "interfering" sidelobes from the other components will always be sufficiently lower to not effect the observable spectrum. If however there was a strong DC offset (or other specular component), then there would be benefit of further widowing to reduce the sidelobes from that component.

Yes. So you might pick a window that minimizes ENBW as it is indicative of spectral resoultion. Fixed that above.
Your answer adresses my first question really well, but only kind of gets at my other question.   I would like to understand this all at a deep theoretical level, which maybe wasn't clear.   Are you aware of any proofs that show that the rectangular window is the best ENBW white-noise solution?  I'm assuming doing it for a different noise color would follow the same logic. Also when computing ENBW for different noise condition, is it just the non-coherent gain term that changes?

@Davey interesting and I’m not aware of any proofs but understand intuitively why a rectangular weighted average provides the best estimate of the mean under white noise conditions specifically (that would be another consideration to factor in). As far as the bandwidth you could compare the total integrated noise under the Kernel of different windows, but given all the common windows have symmetric Kernels I would suspect the change in total noise versus signal for any spectral component would be the same (but worth trying that analysis specifically.

Also note that the bandwidth (spectral shape) of the window itself doesn’t change with the shape of the noise, so the primary consideration to me for spectral analysis would be how much a particular window minimizes the effect of distant energy upon a particular spectral component of interest (in other words the accuracy of the spectral result) - if we overdue that we lose resolution unnecessarily hence the justification in your case to use the rectangular window since I expect you would maintain excellent accuracy without further windowing.

The equivalent noise bandwidth is defined as
\begin{equation}
ENBW = N\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w^{2}[n]}{\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w[n]\right)^{2}}
\end{equation}
The Cauchy-Schwartz inequality states
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{n-0}^{N-1}a[n]b[n]\right)^{2} \leq \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a^{2}[n]\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}b^{2}[n]
\end{equation}
We can see that if we let $b[n] = 1 \, \forall \, n$ and let $\left\{a[n]\right\} = \left\{w[n]\right\}$, we get
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w[n]\right)^{2} \leq N \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w^{2}[n]
\end{equation}
We see that the RHS is the numerator, whereas the LHS is the denominator. Therefore the $ENBW \geq 1$. Equality holds if $\left\{a[n]\right\}$ and $\left\{b[n]\right\}$ are linearly dependent, in this case if one is a scalar multiple of the other. Since $\left\{b[n]\right\}$ is constant with respect to $n$, this means that the window which minimizes the ENBW is the rectangular window.
The ENBW can also be written as
\begin{equation}
ENBW = \frac{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left\lvert W(f)\right\rvert^{2}df}{\left\lvert W(0)\right\rvert^{2}}
\end{equation}
for white noise. However, in general we would have something like
\begin{equation}
ENBW = \frac{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left\lvert W(f)\right\rvert^{2}N(f)df}{\left\lvert W(f_{0})\right\rvert^{2}}
\end{equation}
where $N(f)$ is the noise spectrum. Plugging in for pink noise gives
\begin{equation}
ENBW = \frac{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\left\lvert W(f)\right\rvert^{2}}{f}df}{\left\lvert W(0)\right\rvert^{2}}
\end{equation}
This appears to be a much more difficult equation to minimize with respect to $W(f)$.

This is great. In order to minimize this correctly, I would need to specify some constraints,  probably $0 < \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|W(f)|^2df$, $0< |W(0)| < \infty$, $W(f)=W(-f)$? Anything else?
